# How to display graph and Video file in a single frame/Window in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, graph, wxpython

[I want something similar like this image and this is same layout which I supposed to want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4FXc.jpg)

And with additional note,I want to generate a graph based on the video file timings.For Eg. 10 sec this graph should be generated and after 20 sec another graph should be generated.

Is this possible

Comment: Please someone help me to figure out this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted to show that it's even possible to update the plot for each frame at video rate using [wx pyhotn](https://www.wxpython.org/).

This example will calculate the average pixel intensity along x-axis and update the plot for every frame. Since you want to update every 10 sec, you will need some modification. This Clip (Jenny Mayhem) is taken from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOcgOnBe5Ag

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg') # not sure if this is needed

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas

import wx

class VideoPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent, size):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1, size=size)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.parent = parent
        self.SetDoubleBuffered(True)
    
    def OnPaint(self, event):
        dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self)
        dc.Clear()
        if self.parent.bmp:
            dc.DrawBitmap(self.parent.bmp,0,0)


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, fp):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        
        self.bmp = None
        
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(fp)
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()
        h,w,c = frame.shape
        print w,h,c

        videopPanel = VideoPanel(self, (w,h))

        self.videotimer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnUpdateVidoe, self.videotimer)
        self.videotimer.Start(1000/30.0)

        self.graph = Figure() # matplotlib figure
        plottPanel = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.graph)
        self.ax = self.graph.add_subplot(111)

        y = frame.mean(axis=0).mean(axis=1)
        self.line, = self.ax.plot(y)
        self.ax.set_xlim([0,w])
        self.ax.set_ylim([0,255])

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(videopPanel)
        sizer.Add(plottPanel)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.Fit()
        self.Show(True)


    def OnUpdateVidoe(self, event):
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()
        if ret:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            img_buf = wx.ImageFromBuffer(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], frame)
            self.bmp = wx.BitmapFromImage(img_buf)

            # modify this part to update every 10 sec etc...
            # right now, it's realtime update (every frame)
            y = frame.mean(axis=0).mean(axis=1)
            self.line.set_ydata(y)
            self.graph.canvas.draw()

        self.Refresh()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    fp = "Jenny Mayhem and The Fuzz Orchestrator - Gypsy Gentleman (Live at the Lodge on Queen).mp4"
    app = wx.App(0)
    myframe = MyFrame(fp)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: But only video is showing not the graph can you suggest me how to resolve this

Comment: mac or PC? any error message? which versions of wx, matplotlib, python?

Comment: I am using PC running in windows ,python is 3.5,and wx and matplotlib is the current updated version and can you tell me how the graph get plotted ,is it from any text file or something?

Comment: You may need to telll matplitlib to use wxagg backend by `matplotlib.use('wxagg') `.  Other than that, i do not see why this code does not work in your PC.

Comment: Thank for your patience for helping me throughout.I got this video alone but I can't see a graph in the frame,I was so pleased that if you help me out.Can you tell me where the graph values to be given.

Comment: `self.line.set_ydata(y)` is updating the graph. `self.line` is obtained by plotting something with `self.line, = self.ax.plot(y)`. By the way, the sample code I wrote works on your system as it is?? If so, can you post the code you are working on here? Otherwise, it would be difficult to help..

Comment: what is `wx`?  a library?

Comment: https://www.wxpython.org/